# Can't Convert Json to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is my Ajax response from database :

```
{
    "docs": [{
        "_id":"5be81e62-f91d-4185-bef5-2eabdf048578",
        "_rev":"6-171639a97982fd7d04a81ed070b2e752",
        "profile_id":"5be81e62-f91d-4185-bef5-2eabdf048578",
        "name":"omar"
    }],
    "bookmark": "g2wAAAABaANkAB9kYmNvcmVAZGI1LmplbmV2ZXIuY2xvdWRhbnQubmV0bAAAAAJuBAAAAADAbgQA_____2poAkY_8AAAAAAAAGEBag"
}
```

I want to convert it to jQuery for Example :

```
var JsonData = jQuery.parseJSON(responseData.Value);
alert(JsonData.docs._id);
```

But the alert message show : `undefined`
Need your help please and thanks.

Comment: JsonData.docs[0]._id, JsonData.docs is an Array with no property called _id. It enumerates at least one object (in position 0), which does hold a property called _id.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/egszmgex/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docs` is an *array*. An arrays store multiple `docs` in a single variable.

You need to tell the runtime *which* `doc` you want to attain the `_id` property of.

In your case there is only one `doc` so you can access the first using an *index initializer*:

```
alert(JsonData.docs[0]._id);
```

The `[0]` part pulls the first `doc` from the array.